# configure libdnet under Cygwin+MinGW

Tags: python, scapy

I'm trying to use scapy on win python2.7.
When I configure libdnet under Cygwin+MinGW,there is a problem that checking for Python... configure: error: need MingW32 package to build under Cygwin.
Can some help me in this ?

PS:
i have worked out my problem just now,but i have a new problem.After running setup.py,it warns me that ../include\dnet/os.h(26) : error C2371: "ssize_t": ???;??????

Comment: I've read it already.After doing ./configure,i have this problem

Comment: did you install mingw?

Comment: yes,but i do not know how to associate mingw with cygwin

Comment: Support for Scapy on Windows, per this page http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/doc/installation.html#windows, seems less stable than support for other platforms. It may be possible that what you're trying to do will not work without working around one or more issues.

Comment: i have worked out my problem just now,but i have a new problem.After running setup.py,it warns me that ../include\dnet/os.h(26) : error C2371: "ssize_t": ???;??????